# Any classical music written for dancing?

Tags: classical-music, composers, dance

I thought about it the other day - Virtually all popular music in the 20th century was written for the dance floor.

Is there any classical music written specifically for dances? I think I don't know any. I mean music that the composer intended people to actually dance to. Dance and movement is such a primal thing, so it's weird to me that I can't think of examples.

I don't count things like Bach suites for violin, cello etc. - these are dance **forms**, But I don't think he really meant for people to dance to this, same goes for Chopin waltzes and Mazurkas IMO. Also not Tchaikovsky ballets - it's dance alright, but not for the audience to dance.

Surely some composers composed music for the dance floor of their patron... Do you know any examples?

Comment: Why don't you think that Bach's movements which were named as dances were actually to be danced to? What do you think people did dance those dances to?

Comment: Sarabandes, gavottes, minuets, galliardes, the list is long. How are you classifying 'classical'?

Comment: Where do you get the idea that "Virtually all popular music in the 20th century was written for the dance floor."? That is just so patently incorrect as to be risible.

Comment: I don't know if Johann Strauss composed specifically for the dance floor, but his waltzes are quite danceable ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CTYymbbEL4&list=RD_CTYymbbEL4&start_radio=1&t=184 )

Comment: @NickQuant  Not to mention the rest of the Strauss dynasty!

Comment: Of course the Strauss father and son were writing for dance floors. And then mind the dance scenes of operas and all the menuets  and other dances (passe pied, gavotte etc.) at the courts.

Comment: @danmcb I just can't imagine a crowd dancing to the solo violin/cello suites. Wouldn't it be just too quiet over the sound of... feet? Also IMO the music isn't very...dancy. Maybe it's just modern interpretation? Possibly the orchestral suites and maybe the keyboard suites (french, italian and so on) would be a good fit - but I never saw anyone saying that this was their intention

Comment: @Tetsujin - Pointed example: "My Heart Will Go On", which was written for a late 20th-century **movie** meant to be primarily shown in movie theaters where you cannot dance.

Comment: @tetsujin Ok, you're right, i take it back... Not virtually all music. Some of The most selling records in 20th century were rock albums, by the likes of the beatles and pink floyd, which are not meant for dance. But dance music does have huge presence. My point is - people always liked to dance, and contemporary music was written for this. I think they were always popular dance tunes. So are they any examples by the e familiar composers?

Comment: @Yossi well for one thing you can play those pieces many ways. I used to practice Bach on sax and clarinet and let me tell you you can swing the *** out of it. It's definitely danceable. Second, your 2019 idea of "danceable" is not what people would have considered booty shaking back in 17xx. Third, the volume issue is just about instrumentation. People were accustomed to acoustic music then that was generally much lower in volume than now. Think about it.

Comment: Apparently there's a lot of dance music by Mozart https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart_and_dance

Comment: @danmcb: Whaaaat? No twerking in the early 17th century? No way!  ;)

Comment: @Willem I know, what a shocker :-)

Comment: Actually, not a bad question... just that some of the assumptions are a bit misguided. I will +1 you tomorrow (already used all my votes for today.)

Comment: @danmcb and others, The OPs exclusion of Baroque, keyboard dance suites seem like a fair caveat as those were stylized dances meant for listening not social dance accompaniment. The question isn't really about danceability, it's about the intended purpose of the composition. I think the OP simply doesn't know about the terms _stylized_ dance suite and _social_ dancing.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any classical music written specifically for dances? I think
>   I don't [know] any.

You have essentially answered your question - albeit, by excluding much of the classical music that was composed specifically for the purposes of dancing to it... Also, there are quite a few misconceptions in your question.

For starters, you seem to have a misunderstanding of the meaning of "Dance Forms." These are compositions that are made for a specific [type or style (or "form") of dance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Dance_forms_in_classical_music)... The word form in this case refers to a dance and not a '[musical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_form),' such as [Strophic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strophic_form) or [Binary form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_form); of which a 'dance form' may or may not be composed. Composers MOST DEFINITELY intended for people to dance to these compositions. And, patrons would commission composers for the explicit purpose of writing dance music for their courts.

Secondly:

> ballets - it's dance alright, but not for the audience to dance.

While this may be arguable in our modern age, ballet was very much intended for audience participation during the classical period. From [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_dance#15th%E2%80%9319th_centuries:_from_court_dancing_to_Romanticism):

> The origins of ballet dancing can be traced to the Italian Renaissance
>   courts of the 15th century. Dance masters would teach the steps to
>   nobility and the court would participate in performances as a form of
>   social entertainment. This practice continued for several centuries.

Finally, what you consider as "dance-y" is a subjective perspective likely due to circumstances of our modern society. Just as music that is 'popular' has changed since the 15th century, it is simply natural for preferences to change over time about music with which to dance, as well... For example, much jazz was originally [created for the purpose of dancing to it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazz_dance). But, I would agree with someone that argued that a lot of that music doesn't feel or sound "dance-y" at all - even though the "[Jazz Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazz_Age)" is barely 100 years old and much of that music is made with a drum-kit/trap-kit which is (arguably) THE instrument needed for making modern dance music.

Answer (score 1):

I think you make good point to exclude *stylized dances* like Baroque keyboard suites where the music fits the general meter and tempo of dance styles, but wasn't actually used for dance accompaniment and ballet where the *audience* did not dance.

Having acknowledged that there was classical music written with the intention to accompany actual social dancing. Mozart's various German dances and sets of minuets come to mind. Waltzes from many composers also.

I think the important thing to look for are *orchestration* where a large ensemble was used to provide enough sound to fill the dance space, and dances in a set where the composer created enough material to cover the length of a dance event. This was the kind of material used to accompany social dancing.

Also, you can find lots of collections of dance tune which were published simply on piano staff, often figured bass with melody in the treble. I've seen such sets title like "for flute or violin" or something similar. That kind of material would have been used for actual dancing, but probably for smaller events.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a whole lot of music for Viennese Waltz in formal or ballroom settings that is not both actively used for dancing as well as considered classical music.